# Importing hdhomerun channels into MythTV

Tags: linux, command-line

I am setting up a MythTV backend, to stream Live TV from.

I scanned for channels with the hdhomerun_config utility, and got [this](http://pastebin.com/MvSHSBLE)

However, I really don't have a clue how to import it into MythTV.

Answer (score 0):

Scan for channels from inside MythTV.